# How to write a class to read the sensor value in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am a beginner in Android. I am want to read some sensor value such as accelerometer and gyroscope.
I read the tutorial on website and found that it should use SensorEventListener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{...}
```

But I want to write a class to read sensors values and rather that in MainActivity as it seems writing in Main is not following the "Software Engineering" rules. Is it possible to write as below:

```
public class DataCollection implements SensorEventListener{...}
```

And use MainActivity to call the DataCollection to read sensor value and return to MainActivity?

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor).

So you can separate the SensorEventListener from your MainActivity. You just have to correctly register your listener in the MainActivity (replace 'this' by your DataCollection object):

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(yourDataCollectionObject, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

and you also have to unregister it:

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(yourDataCollectionObject);
```

It should work correctly.

EDIT: you can try it this way.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    DataCollection mDataCollection = null;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDataCollection = new DataCollection(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mDataCollection.register();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mDataCollection.unregister();
    }
}

public class DataCollection implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mLight;

    public DataCollection(Context context){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mLight = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1){
        // TODO

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0){
        // TODO

    }

    public void register(){
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void unregister(){
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. In the DataCollection class, Do I need to do this statement setContentView(R.layout.main)?

Comment: No, you don't have (this is used to display the ui). Moreover, `onCreate` is used in the activity, not the listener. You should use a normal constructor.

Comment: But in the class(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); the getSystemService has error since the class is not extends to Activity

Comment: I edited my answer. `getSystemService` needs to be called from a `Context`. `Activity` extends from `Context` so you can call `getSystemService` directly in an `Activity`. To use `getSystemService` in `DataCollection`, put the context in the constructor.

Comment: I want to show the sensor value in text view, how to pass the values back to the Activity?

Comment: You can create an interface `DataCollectionListener` which contains an `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0)` method. Then your `Activity` implements this interface and you can update your `TextView` in the `onSensorChanged` method.

Comment: Does it work if there are more than one class pass data to the Activity, is there any method like delegate

Comment: I think it works with more than one class but I don't know if there is any method like delegate, sorry.

Comment: Needed a way to have a Sensor object on another non-activity class, this solution was it. Thanks! +1